# my compiler gives an error E0393 using a pointer to an incomplete type of the "String" class::Srep" is not allowed in inline functions

Tags: c++, string

I tried to write a custom type from a book, my compiler gives an error
E0393 using a pointer to an incomplete type of the "String" class::Srep" is not allowed

in inline functions

I understand this error, but how to fix it

```
 class String {
    struct Srep;
    Srep* rep;
    class Cref;
public:
    class Range {};

    String();
.....
    ~String();

    inline void check(int i) const  {if (0 > i or rep->sz <= i) throw Range();}
    inline char read(int i)const { return rep->s[i]; }
    inline void write(char c, int i) { rep = rep->get_own_copy(); }
    inline Cref operator[](int i) { check(i); return Cref(*this,i); }
    inline char operator[](int i)const { check(i); return rep->s[i]; }
    inline int size() const { return rep->sz; }
};
struct String::Srep
{
    char* s;
    int sz;
    int n;
    Srep(int nsz, const char* p)
    {
        n = 1;
        sz = nsz;
        s = new char[sz + 1];
        strcpy(s, p);
    }
    ~Srep() { delete[] s; }
    Srep* get_own_copy()
    {
        if (n == 1) return this;
        n--;
        return new Srep(sz, s);
    }
    void assign(int nsz, const char* p)
    {
        if (sz != nsz)
        {
            delete[] s;
            sz = nsz;
            s = new char[sz + 1];
        }
        strcpy(s, p);
    }
private:           //предотвращаем копирование
    Srep(const Srep&);
    Srep operator= (const Srep);
};
```

Comment: Think about the order in which you do things. When you use the `Srep` struct inside the `String` class, you don't have the full definition of the structure, the compiler simply doesn't know what members it might or might not have.

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, like including a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the full build log when asking about build errors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll  ask better next time

Answer (score 0):

Like you do not need to define nested classes inline in class you also do not need to define inline functions inline in class. And so you make sure that whatever some thing uses is defined before usage. Like that:

```
#include <iostream>

class String {
    struct Srep;
    Srep* rep;
public:
    class Range {};

    inline void check(int i) const;
};

struct String::Srep {
    int sz;
};

void String::check(int i) const {
    if (0 > i or rep->sz <= i) throw Range();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "works!\n";
}
```